# cant fix bad object HEAD error with git status

Tags: git

My Battery died on my macbook when pushing my repo.
Now I cannot run `git status`

```
$ git status
fatal: bad object HEAD
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
```

I've tried a few suggestions ive found for fixing bad object errors.

```
$ git fsck --full
dangling tree 65e856976b7aa7c73f15cd71defedb8a3d622a10
```

I've tried `git prune` and `git prune-packed`

I can still commit, stash, push, it appears to be just affecting git status

Andy ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I had the exactly same problem. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 33):

I guess you solved this problem already but i had this to and could fix it simply by run

```
git pull
```

This has resulted into a working condition. eventough your files are intact you should backup your local git directory and then run the git pull. after that you should be back in business.

If there are files deleted (it should not happen) you can copy them back over a working checkout and commit them from there.

Comment: This worked for me but had to `git stash` local changes first before it allowed me to pull. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your `.git/HEAD` is corrupted or points to a corrupted object, you can change it manually or by `git checkout`.

Comment: Hi tried, doesn't make any difference. HEAD points to refs/heads/master

Comment: although, refs/heads/master doesn't exist.

Comment: So you need to checkout a real branch (and/or restore `refs/heads/master` if it existed). Note though, that refs are usually in `.git/packed-refs` now.

Comment: I've restored refs/heads/master with the correct sha, still same error. same error when running `checkout` too

Comment: I've tried restoring the .git folder from an exact working version but still getting the same error... very strange

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I accidentally added my bin/ folder in an Eclipse Java project.

Using 'git pull' did not work for me.

I fixed it by:

1. closing Eclipse
2. rm -rf bin
3. git rm bin

Then I was able to 'git commit' and continue normally.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: This will remove all you code what ever you have developed and reset into the initial state. You might end up loosing your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --soft origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add all of your modified files with `git add filepath/file.ext` before the git status.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout -f *branchname*` worked for me.